# Row count based on text search

Tags: t-sql

I am working with a system that has a poorly designed database.

There is one screen to record not interested outcomes that has a "Not Interested" reason combo and a free text comment section. What happens in the end is that the reason selected on the combo is concatenated to the reason text.

Ending up with this on the database:

```
[Reasons]
'Customer is not interested'
'Customer bought elsewhere'
'Customer is busy'

[Comments]
'Spoke to mr Smith who asked to call laterCustomer is busy'
'hung the phone on meCustomer is not interested'
```

What's the best way to count how many times each reason was used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT Reasons.column,count(*) 
FROM Reasons
INNER JOIN Comments ON(comments.Column like concat(''%',reasons.column,'%'')) 
GROUP BY Reasons.column
```

Comment: Perfect! Simple and beautiful solution. Thank you!